# Disabling CPU core in u-boot DTS

Tags: cpu, arm, ram, u-boot

I am trying to 'convince' a FriendlyARM ZeroPi (Allwinner H3, 4 x Cortex-A7) that it only has 3 physical cores in the SoC, and there is only 256M of RAM (instead of the 512 actually on board).

I have deleted the lines corresponding to cpu3 in the `sun8i-h3.dtsi` file (found [here](https://github.com/friendlyarm/u-boot/blob/sunxi-v2017.x/arch/arm/dts/sun8i-h3.dtsi)), rebuilt u-boot and flashed it onto the SD card, but to no avail, as linux still picks up the 4th core.

As for the RAM issue, I have only found a comment in [this](https://github.com/friendlyarm/u-boot/blob/sunxi-v2017.x/arch/arm/dts/skeleton.dtsi) file, stating that

> The bootloader will typically populate the memory node

At this point my questions are the following:

1. Why is cpu3 still started, even though it is not present in the DTS?
2. How could I prevent cpu3 from starting at all?
3. How should I specify the memory's size?

I don't want to resort to kernel arguments, as these should be set before even loading the kernel into memory. Furthermore, I don't want to have the ability for Linux to start the 4th core later on, as I could if I used the `maxcpus=3` argument.

The goal would be to run an AMP system where an RTOS has control of the 4th core and a portion of the memory. Hence, I want to completely hide the fact from Linux that there is a 4th core at all. I don't mind changing the kernel, but I have spent hours staring at its source and I still haven't figured out how it gets access to the 4th core. I would like to refrain from a very specific fix, such as hardcoding the kernel to only handle up to 3 cores. I hope there is a more 'dynamic' solution.

Comment: Have you tried using `maxcpus=3` along with another method that denies permission to anyone from bringing the 4th cpu online? Is the idea to prevent a user from doing so or to prevent the system from even knowing about the 4th core? The former is doable, while the latter might require more effort (perhaps even changes in kernel code?).

Comment: How are you going to run this RTOS?  Will it run at the same time as Gnu/Linux? How?

Comment: Is it OK for Gnu/Linux to know about them, but just not use them?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor as an AMP system, it will run at the same time. I would prefer if it didn't know about them, but I start to feel that will not be possible.

Comment: How will you run two OSes at the same time? Which will boot first? Will one be running in the other? Vitalisation? Something else? What is AMP?

Comment: Linux will boot and after that a kernel module will start the RTOS which will have been loaded into memory by u-boot. AMP is Assymetric Multiprocessing.